# java name of folder in which java is installed

Tags: java, windows

Hi is there a chance to find where is java installed on windows ?? Becouse my application use JCE but not all algoritms are installed and I have to download some files
like its writen [here](http://www.ngs.ac.uk/tools/jcepolicyfiles).

Edit:
Another question, how to check if JCE is istall and contains such algotitm (DES) ??

Comment: http://pankaj-k.net/weblog/2004/11/equivalent_of_which_in_windows.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is typically installed under `c:\Program Files\Java\{JRE Release)`

Otherwise you can find the JDK home if it is installed by the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable.

Comment: This answer is not correct. Java is not always installed under `C:\Program Files\Java\...` and the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable is not set by the JDK or JRE installer. It's something that a user has to set by himself. You cannot count on this being always set to find the JDK or JRE installation directory.

Comment: @Jesper, Please note that I said 'typically installed under' meaning that a standard Windows installation on an x86 system.

Comment: @Jesper thanks for anwser, I will always remember it, but now I think it will be OK to check `java.home`

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere around `C:\Program Files\Java\jre6`.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your system privileges, you may be able to look at your environment variables. From what I understand, the `bin` folder of your JRE installation should be included in your `PATH` variable.

You can print this out by typing `path` into a command line ,

or you can find it by right clicking on my computer, and going to properties. Under the Advanced tab, you should see an environment variables button, and your `PATH` will be in the bottom list.